# CSS3 Fade Animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to combine 2 CSS3 Animations that fade in and out. Can anyone help me with this?
This is what I have so far -

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/548LF/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok got your question updated my answer accordingly, the best and the least you can do it is like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/548LF/10/)

[Actual Markup + Styles Required](http://jsfiddle.net/548LF/11/)(Don't use it unless and until CSS3 animations are fully supported by all browsers)

HTML

```
<div class="out"><span>example</span></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
   animation:demo 7s;
   -moz-animation:demo 7s; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-animation:demo 7s; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-animation:demo 7s; /* Opera */
   animation:demo 7s infinite;
}

@keyframes demo {
   0% {opacity:0;}
   50% {opacity:1;}
   100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes demo { /* Firefox */
   0% {opacity:0;}
   50% {opacity:1;}
   100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes demo { /* Safari and Chrome */
   0% {opacity:0;}
   50% {opacity:1;}
   100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-o-keyframes demo { /* Opera */
   0% {opacity:0;}
   50% {opacity:1;}
   100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

Comment: That only fades the div in. My original jsFiddle fades a div in then out- But I am looking to make it short and simple.

Comment: Is there any way the original can be shorted?

Comment: @James done :)..you can remove opera and chrome stuff if you don't need

Comment: @James do you want the animation to stop or you want to go on? and perhaps you should accept correct answers, you are not accepting any answers on your previous questions too

Comment: @James just set the iteration count to 1..http://jsfiddle.net/548LF/13/ but no you cannot hide it after the animation is over, it will pop up back after fading out

Comment: @James that's not the way you accept, you need to tick mark below the rating to accept the correct answer, also accept other's answer on your other questions if they've helped you out, will help other visitors to refer the answers...

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the demo. My original jsFiddle does that but uses more code?

Comment: @James, change 'infinite' to 'forwards'. This way, the animation will stop at opacity: 0; and the div won't pop back up.

Comment: @ChristoferVilander Still pops back up.