# CSS for single division

Tags: html, css, web, css-transitions

I am a beginner, could any one tell me how can i add the below css as an inline style for a single div. because when am attaching it as a css it is working for all the div.. the code is

```
@keyframes blink 


{
0% {
    opacity: 1;
}
50% {
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
}
}
img {
animation: blink 1s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net for demo

Comment: this answer of mine can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979438/css3-fade-animations/13979485#13979485

Comment: and thank you all for the answers..

Comment: Nooo not blink! I thought we did away with this! aaahh!

Answer (score 1):

You say for a single div, but currently your selector is for all images, I'm assuming what you're actually trying to do is apply the animation to all images inside only one div

Your current code:

```
img {
    animation: blink 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Would be updated to something similar to this:

```
div#someId img {
    animation: blink 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Or:

```
div.someClass img {
    animation: blink 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

This is essentially  saying apply the following style to every `img` that is contained within `div#someId` or all divs with the class `someClass`, respectively.

The difference being that using the # (`div#someId`) selects the div element by id, i.e. `<div id="someId"></div>`, but this can/should only be used when there is only one div with that id on the page.

The . (`div.someClass`) selects all divs belonging to a class i.e. , this will select all divs on the page that have their class set to someClass.  It's generally considered good form to use classes instead of id's even if you only expect the element to appear once as it makes the code more flexible i.e., somebody may want to use that same style for another element down the track.

Answer (score 0):

Use a more specific CSS selector.

For instance if you have a div with a id of "foo":

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Then you can apply styles to just that div with the ID selector:

```
#foo {
  styles for this div only
}
```

Here is an overview of different CSS selectors: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref

Answer (score 0):

You can use id or class for a single div like

```
 <div id="abc"></div>
```

Then apply css in a different file or in page

```
 #abc
 {
    opacity:1;
 }
```

OR

```
 <div class="abc"></div>
```

Then apply css in a different file or in page

```
 .abc
 {
    opacity:1;
 }
```

If you use `class` then "." is used while "#" is used for `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inline style, why don't you simply use

```
<div style="animation: blink 1s;animation-iteration-count: infinite;">
```

But you apply this to all images, not divs, with the `img` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  in this sample, we have 3 div that only second div have a ccs style.

HTML:

```
 <div id="d1">This is a first div</div>
    <div id="d2">This is a second div and just this div have a css style</div>
    <div id="d3">This is a third div</div>
```

css:

```
#d2
{
    border:1px maroon dashed;
    background-color:yellow;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    color:blue;
}
```

[you can see result of above code](http://jsfiddle.net/talebihamid/TeGwq/)